# Firebase Get User UID by Email

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm building an admin panel for my firebase application, and would love to manage users a little easier.  I want to be able to look up users by email, and then delete them if necessary.  I understand that fetchSignInMethods will return a value if the user is registered and what provider they have registered with, but is there anyway to query the Authentication tree (not the database tree) to search for a user by email?  It would be nice to be able to get the UID an email is associated to from the Authentication node.

Currently my application only uses email/password authentication(no facebook, twitter, etc) and this is how I check if a user has registered:

```
private func showIfUserIsRegistered(with email: String) {
    Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: email) { (providers, error) in
        if error != nil {
            KVNProgress.showError(withStatus: error.debugDescription)
            return
        }
        let doesntExist = "No, this user doesn't exist."
        let exists = "Yes, user exists and is registered."
        let passwordProvider = "password"
        guard let sources = providers else {
            KVNProgress.showError(withStatus: doesntExist)
            return
        }
        let registered = sources.first == passwordProvider ? exists : doesntExist
        KVNProgress.showSuccess(withStatus: registered)
    }
}
```

I do save information of the user in the database node, and I could query that, however, with over 75k users that call is costly and takes a while to return, and it wouldn't help in cases where the Authentication call to register the user is successful but storing their details to the Database node is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no API in the client SDKs to look up a UID by their email address. Doing this through the database has long been the idiomatic way to do this.

The operation does however exist in the Firebase Admin SDKs. From the [documentation on getting user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data):

> ```
> admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
>   .then(function(userRecord) {
>     // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
>     console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
>   })
>   .catch(function(error) {
>     console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
>   });
> ```

This code is in JavaScript for Node.js, but the Admin SDK also supports this operation in Java, Go, and Python.

The Firebase Admin SDKs are made to be run in trusted environments, such as a server that you control, or Cloud Functions. They run with administrative privileges, and allow full access to the resources in your project. For this reason, they implement certain operations that are not (securely) possible in the client-side SDKs.

So if you don't want to list the users from the database, the common approach is to build a backend (can be quite simple) with the Admin SDKs, and call that from your app. Be sure to secure the backend properly, otherwise you'll lose the security benefits that are introduced by having the Admin SDK be separate from the client SDKs.