# Is There Anyway to retrieve uid From Firebase Authentication wintout login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication

Is There Anyway to retrieve  uid From Firebase Authentication wintout login,  only by using the Email that provided on the time of signup

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality to look up a UID by the user's email address in the client-side SDK. But the functionality exists in Firebase's Admin SDKs. For example, in (server-side) Node.js you could do this with:

```
admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
  });
```

The reason this functionality is only in the Admin SDKs is that those are to be used in a trusted environment, and for many applications having this functionality available in the client might be unwanted. By having the API in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions, you could expose the functionality to your app if that is needed for your use-case.

Alternatively you could store the necessary information in a database (such as Firebase's Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore) and allow users to look it up from there.

Also see: [Firebase Get User UID by Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928500/firebase-get-user-uid-by-email)