# Get user by uid Firebase Auth

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I try to create a friend list, I stock uid of users in firestore of a user, like they are friend, and now I need to get the UserCred by uid for display his name (and do other stuff). I look some questions and all redirect me to the FirebaseAdmin, but I can't use this and don't know why.

I try to do like `FirebaseAdmin.instance.initializeApp().auth()` and here I can get all the users and the function getUser(). Or I try `Auth('app')` but I need to give a App parameter and I don't know how to do this.

The first one with the initialize App, give me every time a null checked error, I look into this [Firebase Get User UID by Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928500/firebase-get-user-uid-by-email) but it's for Swift and the answer don't tell how to get the admin variable. (And on the website of firebase [Firebase/Auth/Admin/Manage_Users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?hl=fr#retrieve_user_data), there is no section for Flutter/Dart for the code)

If someone know how to get UserCred with uid thank you very much !

Comment: There is no way to use the Firebase Admin SDK directly in your Flutter app, as that would be a huge security risk. There is also no way to directly look data for another user by their UID, as that too would be a security risk. --- If you need this functionality you'll either have to have each user store their data in the database, and look it up from there, or you can write your own endpoint (e.g. in Cloud Functions) that your Flutter app calls and that then uses Cloud Functions. In both cases, don't forget to secure access to the user data.

Comment: Right ok, and what a good way to secure access for looking into some data at firestore? Like if I have some name, questions, friends list.. in Users/{uid}/{name|questions|friends}. Do I really need to secure access when looking into theses data and how I can do it ?

Comment: Whether you need to is something only you can decide. But do consider how you'd feel about that same question if you're a user of the app, rather than its developer. Would your users find it acceptable if a malicious could get the names of all their friends and their questions (I think)? --- Writing security rules for your database goes hand in hand with writing the code that accesses the database. So deny all access to the database, run code (fails). Write code for a use-case, run it (fails). Open up the rules to allow only that code to succeed. Run the code (success). On to the next use-case